# GetX Controller not found, you need to call Get.put or Get.lazyPut error when both controllers depend on each other

Tags: flutter-getx

I have two GetX controllers in separate files.  Each depends on each other.  I get the error saying that the "GetX Controller not found, you need to call Get.put or Get.lazyPut" on initialization because one or the other is not created yet.

I looked at lazyput and thought that it might be a solution but I couldn't get it to work.

In C++ I could just do a forward declaration.

What is the correct approach in GetX when there is interdependency like that?

Answer (score 0):

Refer this sample code for GetX controller. [getx_sample](https://github.com/dhola-hardik/flutter_getx_example)

Comment: I looked at some of the files but I can't see how to resolve get.put when one controller depends upon another (they reference each other).

Comment: Can you attach your code? (or github repo url)